# Pushing simple value into an array on the fly

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to create an array with only one value inside of it on the fly without using a variable. This works with a variable:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push('test');
console.log(arr); // correctly logs ["test"]
```

But this does not:

```
console.log([].push('test')); // logs 1
```

Why does this log `1` instead of `["test"]`? Is this coerced into a boolean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new `length` of the array, not the pushed item nor the array it-self.

> "I want to be able to create an array with only one value inside of it
>   on the fly without using a variable"

```
const arr = ['test'];
```

```js
console.log(['test']);
```

Comment: you can also use the spread operator if you want to add elements to an existing array, like so: `const newArray = [...existingArray, newItem]`

Answer (score 2):

[`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

> The `push()` method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and **returns the new length of the array**.

In the first example you are first pushing the element in the array then log the array. But in the second example you are logging the returned result of `push()`.